# Enable to get collection view Cell object in sizeForItemAtIndexPath in swift

Tags: ios, swift

Like in Objective we can get object of Collection View Cell as below. have some issue with Swift

```
-(void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView 
   didSelectItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

DatasetCell *datasetCell = 
  (DatasetCell *)[collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:indexPath];

[datasetCell replaceHeaderGradientWith:[UIColor skyBlueHeaderGradient]];
datasetCell.backgroundColor = [UIColor skyBlueColor]; }
```

Comment: What issue are you facing?

Comment: as given above i am creating object for cell using swift like  "var datasetCell: DatasetCell = collectionView.cellForItemAtIndexPath(indexPath)"  but it is  showing Bed exception..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this :

```
 func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

let datasetCell =  collectionView(collectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath: indexPath) as DatasetCell
datasetCell.backgroundColor = UIColor.blueColor()
```

}